# how to make a distort effect?

Tags: images, photoshop-effects, distort

My English is pretty basic, please don't mind. Wondering how to make the liquify wave and distort color effect in Photoshop? I'd tried using distort>shear/wave/zigzag, but still can't make it similar like the photo below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The tool to use is "filter->distort->displace..."

Comment: Nothing is going to get you close to that in one step. There's no "magic filter" to pull off every possible visual alteration out there. It's going to take a *process* which you'll have to determine. My *guess* would be that image is a result of *physical* warping  to the photo negative during processing (someone folded/rolled a negative and it curled and distorted) and was *not* made digitally in its original form.

Comment: @Scott: as the zoom shows, the printing dots are also distorted, so it would be photo > printed image > photo > distort negative. (It would explain where the color fringes come from – the original b&w would not be able to cause that.) I find myself wonder what the original did look like, though. A simple passport mug shot?

Answer (score 2):

It looks a bit like one of those images taken using the Slit Scan Camera Lite app available for Android, there's probably an iOS version too.  You can move the camera white it scans. Here I simply pointed it at an image on a monitor.

[image]

As for the colour changes/fringing - you could use Photoshop's liquify filter on some of the RGB channels individually.

[image]

The original image [is here](https://cdn8.openculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/09155131/david-bowie-mugshot.png)

Perhaps you could get better results using an actual scanner, and move the copy while it scans.