# How can I recreate this typographical style? What effects/processes should I use?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography, posters

[image: **enter image description here**]

I have been scrolling through various places on the internet and I've come across this typographic style multiple times, and I can't work out how to do it. Can anyone help??

Comment: Have you read about using [displacement maps](https://digital-photography-school.com/get-creative-displacement-maps-photoshop/) in Photoshop?

Comment: It is not a "typographical style" at all – it is applied to text, but that's about it. *Very* similar to the recent https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/104653/30216, possibly even a duplicate.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have dabbled in them, but they are still very new to me